# How to use multiple OrderBy's to an unspecified number in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

So I know you can use OrderBy like so with LINQ:

```
MyList.OrderBy(x => x.foo[0].Value).ThenByDescending(x => x.foo[1].Value);
```

However I am in a situation where I do not know how many properties x.foo will have and I would like to order by all of them. Is this possible?

EDIT: In this instance x.foo is a list of KeyValuePair's where I am sorting by the Value in order of the Keys.

Comment: Just call `ThenByDescending` in a loop. Is this linq to objects or linq to SQL?

Comment: linq to objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided there's at least one item and all the items have the same number of 'foos'

```
int foosPerItem = MyList.First().Foo.Count;

IOrderedEnumerable<T> ordered = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.foo[0].Value);

for (int i = 1; i < foosPerItem; i++)
{
    ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(x => x.foo[i].Value);
}

// added after your comment:
// ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(x => x.bar);
```

Following your other comment about ordering by bar first:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<T> ordered = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.bar);

for (int i = 0; i < foosPerItem; i++)
{
    ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(x => x.foo[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: foo is a List of KeyValuePairs's

Comment: @AzzyDude Does all the foos have the same number of entries?

Comment: Then this should work, you may need extra code to check there's at least one item though

Comment: if you wanted to order between multiple different properties as well, could you just include another 'ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(x => x.bar); inside that loop?

Comment: @AzzyDude, not inside the loop otherwise you'll get duplicates but totally possible after the loop (code updated)

Comment: but if I wanted to orderby x.bar then by x.foo[0] then by x.foo[1], etc...would the x.foo[i]'s in the loop not overtake the x.bar priority?

Comment: @AzzyDude The code I added orders by `bar` first (with highest priority) and then by `foo` values.